# How to count cases by group with n() when there are missing data

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to `summarise` data with mean and number of cases, without counting missing data. Is it possible to do it with `n()`? The expected results for N should be `3, 2`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(g = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, NA, 5))

df %>%
  group_by(g) %>%
  summarise(M = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE),
            N = n()) %>%
  ungroup()
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>       g     M     N
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1     1   2       3
#> 2     2   4.5     3
Created on 2020-12-16 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)
```

Comment: No, not possible with `n()` as it gives the current group size regardless of whether other variables have missing values. You can sum the number of non-NA cases instead.

Comment: I tried these without success: ```count = sum(!is.na(.)), sum = sum(.,na.rm=TRUE))```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `complete.cases` to get a logical vector of complete/not complete rows, then `sum` the vector's values by group.

```
df %>%
  mutate(N = complete.cases(.)) %>%
  group_by(g) %>%
  summarise(M = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE),
            N = sum(N), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  ungroup()
## A tibble: 2 x 3
#      g     M     N
#  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#1     1   2       3
#2     2   4.5     2
```

Comment: If I had another column in df for example ```y = c(NA, NA, 1, 2, 3, 4)``` the result would be wrong. I had to change ```complete.cases(.)``` to ```complete.cases(x)```.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter the data upstream before passing to summarise and that will do.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(g = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, NA, 5))

Answer <- df %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  group_by(g) %>%
  summarise(M = mean(x),
            N = n()) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Gives the folowing output.

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
      g     M     N
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     1   2       3
2     2   4.5     2
```